# passing arrays in curl command to mongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, curl

im using the below mongoDB schema for my data

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const subSchema = require("../../src/models/Course");

const All_CoursesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    Student_name: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    course_names: [ {grade: {type: String, required: true}, course_name: {type: String,required: true}}],
  });
  
  const All_Courses = mongoose.model('Courses', All_CoursesSchema)
  
  module.exports = All_Courses
```

I also have the following api call using express in node.js

```
router.post('/add-courses', (req,res)=>{
  const course = new All_Courses(req.body);
  console.log(course);
  course.save()
      .then((result)=>{
        res.send(result)
      })
      .catch((err) =>{
        console.log(err);
      });
});
```

im trying to pass the parameters using this curl request but it return an empty array with only the student_name set properly

```
curl -X POST -d "Student_name=hadi" -a "course_name=[{grade=78&course_name=cmps}]" http://localhost:5000/api/add-courses
```

how do i make the proper request using curl??, help would be apperiacted

Comment: Even `Student_name=hadi` is not proper javascript; no quotes around the literal "hadi".  Does `new All_Courses(req.body)` actually work....?

Comment: All_courses() works if i hard code my values inside the function. example All_courses(student_name= "x", .....) so im guessing it should function properly if i pass them these values in curl. but i havent been able to test it because i cant figure out the correct format for passing them in curl

Comment: I am pretty sure `req.body` is simply going to be the POST material as a big string, not structured arguments with name and type.   I think what is happening is `student_name = "x"` is being evaluated to `All_courses(student_name)` where `student_name` is a single string variable; in short, you are calling `All_courses("x")`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are mixing text and variable assignment and JSON and javascript.  Let's back up 1 step and assume we want to call our API with well-structured JSON.  So the call to `curl` becomes this:

```
curl -g -X POST -d '{"student_name":"hadi","course_name":[{"grade":78,"course_name":"cmps"}]}' http://localhost:5000/api/add-courses
```

A nice thing about POST is that you don't have to be concerned with URL encoding because spaces, quotes, etc. are not in the URL; they are "safe" in the body of the POST.

This will hit your express/node server as JSON text which you must parse into an object to dp something interesting with it:

```
router.post('/add-courses', (req,res)=>{
  var obj = JSON.parse(req.body);
  const course = new All_Courses(obj);
  ...
```